# 'Unsupported encoding: DELTA_BYTE_ARRAY' while writing parquet data to csv using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert parquet files in binary format to csv files. I am using the following commands in spark.

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString","true")

val source =  sqlContext.read.parquet("path to parquet file")

source.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").save("path to csv")
```

This works when i start spark in HDFS server and run these commands. When I try copying  the same parquet file to my local system and start pyspark and run these commands it is giving error.

I am able to set binary as string property to true and able to read parquet files in my local pyspark. But when I execute the command to write to csv, it gives the following error.

> 2018-10-01 14:45:11 WARN  ZlibFactory:51 - Failed to load/initialize
>   native-zlib library 2018-10-01 14:45:12 ERROR Utils:91 - Aborting task
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: **Unsupported encoding:
>   DELTA_BYTE_ARRAY**
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.initDataReader(VectorizedColumnReader.java:577)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.readPageV2(VectorizedColumnReader.java:627)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.access$100(VectorizedColumnReader.java:47)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader$1.visit(VectorizedColumnReader.java:550)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader$1.visit(VectorizedColumnReader.java:536)
>           at org.apache.parquet.column.page.DataPageV2.accept(DataPageV2.java:141)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.readPage(VectorizedColumnReader.java:536)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.readBatch(VectorizedColumnReader.java:164)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextBatch(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:263)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:161)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:109)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:186)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:109)

What should be done to resolve this error in local machine as the same works in hdfs? Any idea to resolve this would be of great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**
Getting an exception in Spark 2.x reading parquet files where some columns are DELTA_BYTE_ARRAY encoded.

**Exception:**
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported encoding: DELTA_BYTE_ARRAY

**Solution:**
If turn off the vectorized reader property, reading these files works fine.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader", "false")
```

**Explanation:**
These files are written with the Parquet V2 writer, as delta byte array encoding is a Parquet v2 feature. The Spark 2.x vectorized reader does not appear to support that format.
[Issue already created on apache’s jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/SPARK-26509/SPARK-26509.html). To solve this particular work around.

[image: Fig 1.0 Snapshot of Issue.]

**Cons of using this solution.**
Vectorized Query Execution could have big performance improvement for SQL engines like Hive, Drill, and Presto. Instead of processing one row at a time, Vectorized Query Execution could streamline operations by processing a batch of rows at a time. But spark 2.x doesn’t support this feature for parquet version two so we need to rely on this solution until further releases.

Answer (score 5):

You can try disabling the VectorizedReader.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader", "false")
```

This is not a solution but it is a workaround.
Consequences of disabling it will be https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-vectorized-parquet-reader.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding these 2 flags helped me overcome the error.

```
parquet.split.files false
spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader false
```