# Getting error while writing parquet files to Azure data lake storage gen 2

Tags: apache-spark, azure-data-factory, parquet, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

Hi I have a usecase where I am reading parquet files and writing it to ADLG Gen 2. This is without any modification to data.

MY Code:

```
val kustoLogsSourcePath: String = "/mnt/SOME_FOLDER/2023/01/11/fe73f221-b771-49c9-ba7d-2e2af4fe4f2a_1_69fc119b888447efa9ed2ecd7a4ab647.parquet" 
val outputPath: String = "/mnt/SOME_FOLDER/2023/01/10/EventLogs1/" 
val kustoLogData = spark.read.parquet(kustoLogsSourcePath) 
kustoLogData.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save(outputPath)
```

I am getting this error, any ideas how to solve it:
Here, I have shared all the exception related messages that I got.

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:192)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:128)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:143)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:180)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:690)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:690)
at

---

Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 276 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 276.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 351, 10.139.64.13, executor 5): com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file dbfs:[REDACTED]/eventlogs/2023/01/10/[REDACTED-FILE-NAME].parquet.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.logFileNameAndThrow(FileScanRDD.scala:272)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:256)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:197)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.scan_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)

---

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported encoding: DELTA_BYTE_ARRAY
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.initDataReader(VectorizedColumnReader.java:584)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.readPageV2(VectorizedColumnReader.java:634)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.access$100(VectorizedColumnReader.java:49)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader$1.visit(VectorizedColumnReader.java:557)
at

---

Caused by: com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file dbfs:[REDACTED]/eventlogs/2023/01/11/fe73f221-b771-49c9-ba7d-2e2af4fe4f2a_1_69fc119b888447efa9ed2ecd7a4ab647.parquet.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.logFileNameAndThrow(FileScanRDD.scala:272)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:256)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:197)
at

---

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported encoding: DELTA_BYTE_ARRAY
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.initDataReader(VectorizedColumnReader.java:584)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.readPageV2(VectorizedColumnReader.java:634)
at

Comment: Is it because the file is too big ?

Comment: hi @Sumitiscreative , could you please provide the code. what you tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Unsupported encoding: DELTA\_BYTE\_ARRAY' while writing parquet data to csv using pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588408/unsupported-encoding-delta-byte-array-while-writing-parquet-data-to-csv-using)

Comment: Code I used:                                                                                                                                       
    val kustoLogsSourcePath: String = "/mnt/SOME_FOLDER/2023/01/11/fe73f221-b771-49c9-ba7d-2e2af4fe4f2a_1_69fc119b888447efa9ed2ecd7a4ab647.parquet"
    val outputPath: String = "/mnt/SOME_FOLDER/2023/01/10/EventLogs1/"


    val kustoLogData = spark.read.parquet(kustoLogsSourcePath)  
  
    kustoLogData.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save(outputPath)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some columns are DELTA_BYTE_ARRAY encoded, a workaround would be to turn off the vectorized reader property:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader", "false")
```

Answer (score 0):

***Try to modify your code and also remove the string parameter in the font of the variable and also use `.format("delta")` for reading delta file.***

```
%scala

val kustoLogsSourcePath = "/mnt/SOME_FOLDER/2023/01/11/" 
val outputPath = "/mnt/SOME_FOLDER/2023/01/10/EventLogs1/" 
val kustoLogData = spark.read.format("delta").load(kustoLogsSourcePath)
kustoLogData.write.format("parquet").mode("append").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save(outputPath)
```

*For the demo, this is my FileStore location `/FileStore/tables/delta_train/`.*

[image]

**I reproduce same in my environment as per above code .I got this output.**

[image]